# format of the 'TEXT' in OCINumberFromText in C code

Tags: sql, c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I want to insert values like `B194YV` into an array and ultimately to `OCINumber` to use in Oracle statement.

I tried to insert like this

```
rc = OCINumberFromText(errhp, (text*)new_value, strlen(new_value), 
    (text*)"99G999D99", 9, (text *)"NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.''", 27, &num_val);
```

Here `new_value` has value `B194YV`, but it doesnt work. i get error

```
OCI-22062: invalid input string [B194YV]
```

I know `99G999D99` is not the correct format, so can anyone please tell me what format should i write?

Thank you

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't say much. What error are you getting?

Comment: I have updated my question. I get error "OCI-22062: invalid input string [B194YV]"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string "B194YV" to a number. This is simply not possible. It's not a number.